# What is the meaning of these empty array assignments in perl?

Tags: perl

```
foreach my $tp (@tpList)
{
print "inside function 14";
my $result1_fail = "";
$_=$tp;
next if(/^$/);
print "TP : $tp\n";
$result.="<h3>$tp</h3><BR>\n";
$result1_fail.="<h3>$tp</h3><BR>\n";
#------------------------------#
print "inside function 15";
***my @emptytables=();
my @tables=();***
@tables= getAllTables4TP($tp);
```

- Please explain the meaning of  my @emptytables=();
- And also my @tables=();
- is this used for defining some empty array?
- if it is, then what is its use?

Comment: Maybe you want to read about [Perl data structures](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) and the use of [my](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) to declare variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `my @tables;` creates an empty array
- `my @tables = ();` creates an empty array, then replaces its contents with nothing (empties it).
- `my @tables = (); @tables = getAllTables4TP($tp);` creates an empty array, then replaces its contents with nothing, then replaces its contents with something else.

I would use just the following:

```
my @tables = getAllTables4TP($tp);
```

Answer (score 5):

These initialize the arrays as empty and if the next thing is an array assignment, it's basically useless. I would write

```
my @tables = getAllTables4TP($tp);
```

I can't say anything about `@emptytables` because I don't see code using it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are correct, it's defining an empty array.

Check this part

```
my @tables=();
@tables= getAllTables4TP($tp);
```

Here the data insertion is done into the tables array. You can directly write the above lines as one line:

```
my @tables= getAllTables4TP($tp);
```